# Multiple if statements in a loop vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run a simple if statement but can not get it to run for me without getting an error. Basically, I am trying to have multiple if statements within a loop, im guessing i have a minor error but cannot spot it, maybe with the else statements. Any help is appreciated

```
Sub ex13()

Dim rgtimetable As Range, rgR As Range, counter As Integer
Dim counter1 As Integer, counter2 As Integer, counter3 As Integer

Set rgtimetable = Range("timetable")
For Each rgR In rgtimetable
    rgR.Activate
    If classyear(ActiveCell.Value) = 0 Then counter = counter + 1   ' classyear is a function i am calling from above

    Else
    If classyear(ActiveCell.Value) = 1 Then counter = counter1 + 1

    Else
    If classyear(ActiveCell.Value) = 2 Then counter = counter2 + 1

    Else
    If classyear(ActiveCell.Value) = 3 Then counter = counter3 + 1

Next rgR

MsgBox counter
MsgBox counter1
MsgBox counter2
MsgBox counter3

End Sub
```

Comment: `counter = counter1 + 1` should **maybe** be `counter1 = counter1 + 1` (etc)

Comment: @RC. no the counter is working for me when i am trying one if, its when i bring in the other ifs that my counter goes wrong

Comment: Re your comment (to an answer) "I a still having a problem with the counter but not sure what it is. Ill see if i can solve it" - see the comment by @RC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In VBA there are several ways to write an `If` statement:

```
If [some condition] Then [Do something]
```

Or

```
If [some condition] Then [Do something] Else [Do something else]
```

Or

```
If [some condition] Then
   [Do something]
End If
```

Or

```
If [some condition] Then
   [Do something]
Else
   [Do something else]
End If
```

Or, finally

```
If [some condition] Then
   [Do something]
ElseIf [some other condition] Then
   [Do something different]
Else
   [Do something else]
End If
```

In your code your `If` statements are all on one line and therefore don't need a corresponding `End If`, but also can't take a corresponding `Else` statement on a following line. If you want to use an `Else` or an `ElseIf`, you must use the final `If` statement block pattern and close the `If` block with a corresponding `EndIf`.

In your case, as you are always testing the same thing (`classyear(ActiveCell.Value)`), I would advise taking advantage of the `Select Case` construction, which will shorten your code.

```
Select Case classyear(ActiveCell.Value)
Case 0
   counter = counter + 1   ' classyear is a function i am calling from above

Case 1
   counter = counter1 + 1

Case 2
   counter = counter2 + 1

Case 3
   counter = counter3 + 1

Case Else
   'Oops, this shouldn't happen, but handle the error anyway

End Select
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much for your in-depth answer, i have a much better understanding of it now once reading it. I a still having a problem with the counter but not sure what it is. Ill see if i can solve it

Comment: @leonHill I think your problem might be that counter1, counter2 and counter3 are never set to anything. Are you getting any more errors?

Comment: @steveES yeah your right man i forgot to set the counter for 1,2 and 3. I set one half but forgot to do the other half. One last question say if i want the values of the counter to be displayed in a cell instead of in a message box any idea how i would do that ??

Comment: Thanks @YowE3K, I've added it in :)

Comment: @leonHill - you should really ask further questions in a new question.

Comment: @leonHill - That is something you should easily be able to find through a web search :)

Comment: @SteveES You might want to convert your answer into an article for the documentation site of SO: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/topics

Comment: @Ralph Good idea, do you think it would go in getting started, or require a new topic?

Comment: @SteveES I am not even sure they will accept it as an article. But I'd give it a try. Don't worry. These guys are pretty straight forward and will let you know soon enough if they like it (up-votes) or not (down-votes) and how they think you should revise it (comments) or even expand upon it.